# Simplest XSLT Stylesheet whose output is the XSLT Stylesheet...For learning purposes

Tags: xslt, self

What's the simplest XSLT (1.0) stylesheet that can be used to output itself?

I have started it off (and haven't got very far...). `self.xml` is the name of the stylesheet (and the input document):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="self.xml"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
...
```

And the output should be, well the same....

EDIT (after reading about quines from a poster...)

Let me make this request harder...

Does an XSLT stylesheet exist which will just simply output any input document. (I mean output, not just internally represent it) : 'any input document' would include itself of course...

Comment: _"Does an XSLT stylesheet exist which will just simply output any input document"_ Yes, it does. Many of them. But do note that XSLT operates over an XML tree (Infoset/XDM) an that tree is a **logical representation** of the document rarer than the exact source document. In XSLT 2.0 that would be resolved by [`fn:unparsed-text()`](http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/#unparsed-text)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a really short XSLT 1.0 solution :)

Comment: Also added an XSLT 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of program is called a "quine," and a quick Google of "XSLT quine" resulted in this link: http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/#quine

Comment: nice one. Thanks for the new term as well...actually although both these examples (self.xslt and quine.xslt) are interesting (especially the second one): they both to a certain extent 'cheat' it seems: the first one (which the author also labels as a 'cheat'), doesn't seem to output anything (but it presumably DOES build an internal rep of the input doc), the second contains it's own copy of "...<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0".." in a variable. This is fine (I guess) since this is what is always wanted; or maybe this has to be the case ? Not sure...

Comment: Actually the second example (now that I have actually read the definition of 'quine' - great stuff by the way - thanks for introducing me to that!), is indeed a genuine quine: it has no input document. I *think* what I meant here is actually an XSLT which can taken ANY input - including itself: and reproduce it...

Comment: That's just the identity transform, then.

Answer (score 1):

**I haven't clicked on the link to Oliver Becker, but the first that comes to mind is this**:

**XSLT 1.0**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to any XML document (not used), the result is exactly the same as the code above**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('')" />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="unparsed-text(static-base-uri())"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks again: actually the first example is the same as given on Oliver Becker's page: firefox renders this as a blank output, which threw me I guess. I'll upvote this, and accept Steven Huwig's answer since he pointed me at it first. Thanks very much for your examples again!

Comment: @monojohnny: You are welcome. Please, note that my XSLT 2.0 solution has no parallel in Becker's page.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for the identity transform instead, Wikipedia has a few examples.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform